# Updating button events in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am creating a Check List app and trying to update button event which is set images itself after clicked.

**Here is my code:**

```
protocol CustomeCellDelegate { 
   func cell(cell: UITableViewCell, updateTheButton button: UIButton)
}

class Cells: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var checkBox: UIButton!
    var buttonPressed = true
@IBAction func checkBoxAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if buttonPressed {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkBoxB"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        buttonPressed = false
    } else {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:""), for: UIControlState.normal)
        buttonPressed = true
    }
}
 @objc func recordButtonImage(_ button: UIButton) {
    cellDelegate?.cell(cell: self, updateTheButton: button)  // cell notify the button that touched.
}
override func awakeFromNib() {
    checkBox.addTarget(self, action: #selector(recordButtonImage(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)  
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate, CustomeCellDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var myImages: [UIImage?]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.delegate   = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    myImages = Array(repeatElement(nil, count: 50))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "Cells", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cells")
 }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 50
}

internal func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "theCells") as? Cells
        cell?.theTextField.delegate = self
        cell?.cellDelegate = self
        cell?.checkBox.setImage(myImages[indexPath.row], for: UIControlState.normal)

    return cell!        
}

// This function from protocol and it helps to update button images.
func cell(cell: UITableViewCell, updateTheButton button: UIButton) {
    print("Delegate method Update Button Images.")
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell), let buttonImage = button.image(for: UIControlState.normal) {
        myImages[indexPath.row] = buttonImage
    }
}
```

I would like to update both events of the **button** that set image after **checked** and **unchecked**. Therefore, my table view can dequeue Reusable Cell and have those events updated.

But the result is just one event of button which is checked updated but not the unchecked one. The checked button still repeats whatever I do to uncheck it.

Comment: Can you please explain what does `I would like to record both events of the button that set image after checked and unchecked.` mean?

Comment: @InderKumarRathore Hello, I just edit that statement and hope it will make my question clearer. Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: Does your `checkBoxAction` action is connected with the `checkBox` button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need `recordButtonImage` method, you should call the delegate method from the button tapped action i.e. `checkBoxAction`, just like below

```
class Cells: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
  @IBOutlet weak var checkBox: UIButton!
  var buttonPressed = true
  @IBAction func checkBoxAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if buttonPressed {
      sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkBoxB"), for: UIControlState.normal)
      buttonPressed = false
    } else {
      sender.setImage(UIImage(named:""), for: UIControlState.normal)
      buttonPressed = true
    }
    // cell notify the button that touched.
    cellDelegate?.cell(cell: self, updateTheButton: button)
  }
}
```

Also your data source method, doesn't tell the cell whether the button was pressed or not. It just sets the image but doesn't set the variable `buttonPressed`

```
 internal func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "theCells") as? Cells
  cell?.theTextField.delegate = self
  cell?.cellDelegate = self
  cell?.checkBox.setImage(myImages[indexPath.row], for: UIControlState.normal)

  return cell!
}
```

Comment: It worked, wonderful. Thanks Rathore for your help, I checked again the steps that you mentioned above and also by mistake, I did not  give any image data for the unchecked button in my function, so i made one.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle **UIButton** is using its own state.

You need to hold current state value in one array. So you can keep the state in cellForRow and other things. By default set all state to **false**.

In CellForRow, just put below code:

```
  YOUR_BUTTON.isSelected = aryState[indexPath.row] as! Bool
```

Set image for your button

```
YOUR_BUTTON.setImage(UIImage(named: NORMAL_IMAGE), for: .normal)
YOUR_BUTTON.setImage(UIImage(named: SELECTED_IMAGE), for: .selected)
```

Just change button state when it clicked:

```
@IBAction func checkBoxAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let button = sender
    button.isSelected = !button.isSelected
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nirmalsinh for your help, I checked your method and I would say it's much more better than mine, but there is still one problem that I could not find out, is the protocol not updating my button's state to the Cells. I did not find a way to do it, but if you can, I would love to know more detail.